# How to compare 2 vectors using a for loop?

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have an "out of range" vector apparently, and need help catching the error. I want to iterate through a find function with each element in the vector, checking within another vector.

```
for(int i=1201; i <= memoryQueue.size(); i++){
    //cacheLookUp = find(cacheQueue.begin(), cacheQueue.end(),memoryQueue.at(i));

    //while(cacheLookUp != cacheQueue.end()){
        if(find(cacheQueue.begin(), cacheQueue.end(), memoryQueue.at(i)) != cacheQueue.end()){ // <<-- Problem here
            cacheHit++;
        }
        else{
            cacheMiss++;
        }
    //}

    cout << "Element in memeory: " << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: `int i=1201` is an odd place to start indexing

Comment: Did you mean to do `< memoryQueue.size()` instead of `<= memoryQueue.size()`  ?

Comment: and `memoryQueue.at(i)) != cacheQueue.end()` is an odd way to write a predicate

Comment: your `find` tries to find a `true` or `false` in the vector depeding on `memoryQueue.at(i)) != cacheQueue.end()`. You probably wanted to use a lambda and pass it to `find`

Comment: You can use the contains() method

Comment: There are some problems with the code, but I dont see how you would get a out of range. Are you sure about the error?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, you're right, let me go ahead and change that.

Comment: Let me go ahead and make these changes.

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question. Latest when there is already an answer that isnt something nice to do. You are asking to fix the code. If you fix the code in your question, there is no question anymore and given answers become meaningles.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the minor problems with i=1201 now-> i=1.  I changed <= memoryQueue.size() to  <memoryQueue.size().  Now I'm not out of range anymore.  Now the problem is, I don't get any Cache Miss.

Comment: @tobi303 I'm not editing the question.  I meant try it in my IDE.  Thanks for the heads up though

Comment: I see. no problemo then. Btw I overlooked one small detail that causes your out of range, see GillBates answer...

Answer (score 1):

You using the following for loop:

```
for(int i=1201; i <= memoryQueue.size(); i++)
```

When you try to access `memoryQueue` in last iteration

```
i = memoryQueue.size()
```

using `memoryQueue.at(i)` it is simply out of range (remember position starts at 0)

Even though I am not sure what you are trying to achieve,

```
for(int i=1201; i < memoryQueue.size(); i++)
```

should solve the out of range problem

Comment: What I'm trying to do is go through every element in the Vector1 and check if that element is within Vector2.  That was a big mistake on my part with for(int i=1201; i < memoryQueue.size(); i++).   I have fixed it the "out of range" problem.  Now, I'm not getting any Cache Miss.  I'm just getting Cach Hit.

Comment: @AndresVal I think you need to revisit the arguments on std::find; in particular the last one.

Comment: @AndresVal The code looks fine. Are you sure the problem is not with the data?

Comment: @AndresVal What type of variable do the vectors contain?